# Traversing to the last child element in a tree using jQuery selector

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="myDIV">
 <div>
  <span>
    <a href="#">Seek me!</a>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I find **A** tag using jQuery selector (not looping through children())
If I know only myDIV id.

Well, it really sounds a bit awkward. For example I've clicked #myDIV and i need to get text from the last child tag. It could A, span, div, p, whatever. Also myDIV could not even have any children elements.

Excuse me my English

Comment: What if there are 2 at the same depth?

Comment: @Nick Craver presumably the is always only one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("#myDIV :not(:has(*))")
```

This will find all the last "leaf" elements, you could restrict to only `<a>`, etc if you wanted.  For your markup:

```
$("#myDIV :not(:has(*))").text() // "Seek me!"
$("#myDIV :not(:has(*))").length // 1
```

[`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) doesn't work here (because it has a text node child), but finding things with no child elements will, [here's an example page showing this](http://jsfiddle.net/GppV6/).

Comment: @downvoter - Enlighten us on a better method?  Seeing as every other answer here doesn't work I find it interesting you down-vote the only answer that does.

Comment: @Nick: I'll even it out for you :-) I had to re-read the question a few times, though.

Comment: how can i adjust your code if i use $(this) to define the clicked element? thanks

Comment: @dr3w - Which element are you clicking?, the `#myDIV`?

Comment: @dr3w - Whatever `this` is, you can do `$(this).find(":not(:has(*))")` if you need to sometimes include even the element clicked, then:  `$(this).find(":not(:has(*))").andSelf().filter(":not(:has(*))")`

Answer (score -1):

It's just `$('#myLink')`