# How to Find Leaf Element From XML Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

i have a XML file which is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<childrens>
 <child id="1" value="Root Catalog" parent_id="0">
  <child id="2" value="Apparel" parent_id="1">
    <child id="3" value="Accessories" parent_id="2">
        <child id="4" value="Handbags" parent_id="3">
            <child id="5" value="Jewelry" parent_id="4"/>
            <child id="6" value="test1" parent_id="4"/>
            <child id="7" value="test2" parent_id="4"/>
            <child id="15" value="test3" parent_id="4"/>
        </child>
    </child>
  </child>
  <child id="8" value="test_A" parent_id="1">
    <child id="9" value="test_B" parent_id="8">
        <child id="10" value="test_C" parent_id="9">
            <child id="11" value="test_D" parent_id="10"/>
        </child>
    </child>
  </child>
 </child>
</childrens>
```

now i want to find the leaf element of a particular elements

for example i want to find leaf element of `Apparel`

which is `Jewelry, test1, test2, test3` so i want this as my output

i have written this jQuery code to find leaf element

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "test.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {
    $(xml).find('child:empty').filter('child[value="Apparel"]').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id)
    });
}
});
```

if i use only `child:empty` then it gives me all the leaf element

mine code is not working ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the question [Traversing to the last child element in a tree using jQuery selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744251/traversing-to-the-last-child-element-in-a-tree-using-jquery-selector)

You can do it this way:

```
$(text).find('child[value="Apparel"]').find(':not(:has(*))').each(function(i, item) {
    console.log($(item).attr('id') + " : " + $(item).attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: Please Copy The XML file then you can figure out `test_D` is not leaf node of `Apparel`. you can also understand by `id` and `parent_id`. `test_D` is leaf node of `test_A`